# How to freeze Facebooker gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I tried rake gems:unpack, it worked for most gems, but facebooker gem doesn't get frozen.

How to freeze it?

Thanks

Comment: I created a new Rails 2.3 app, put config.gem "facebooker" in environment.rb and ran rake gems:unpack and everything seemed to work fine.

Could you give more details about rails and gem version and any specific error messages you're getting?

Comment: I found it... maybe, thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple...

Apparently when in your environment.rb you included several gems, and one of the gems is broken or included with wrong syntax (perhaps it needs lib options for example config.gem "ruby-openid", :lib => "openid") all the gems below that gem won't be unpacked. Funny though how Rails doesn't return an error when you ruby script/server it.